# How to make an activity can not be exitable without certain action?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm making a parental control app where the app will ask for a password at a certain time. I want the activity where the app ask for a password can not be exitable before the parent give the right password. How can I do that?

Comment: What do u mean by exitable? Does it mean go to the previous activity by pressing back button?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

then in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
 }
```

To disable Home Button

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

To disable Back Button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// Do nothing or catch the keys you want to block
}
```